# table vue.js with json on laravel

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to show result from json to table with vue.js 
i have no result this is the script:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="title">Progress Queue's details Live</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content table-responsive table-full-width">
            <el-table :data="tableData2">
              <el-table-column label="Name" property="name"></el-table-column>
              <el-table-column class="danger" label="Numbers"       property="numbers"></el-table-column>
            </el-table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script>

  import ChartCard from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/ChartCard.vue'
  Vue.use(Table)
  Vue.use(TableColumn)
  const WorldMap = () => ({
    component: import('./../Maps/WorldMap.vue'),
    loading: Loading,
    delay: 200
  })


 import axios from 'axios';
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import {Table, TableColumn} from 'element-ui'
 Vue.use(Table)
 Vue.use(TableColumn)
 // Vue.use(tableRowClassName)

import vSelect from 'vue-select';
//Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

  export default {
    components: {
      vSelect,
      StatsCard
    },

    data () {

      return {
     tableData2: [],
},
      mounted() {


    axios.get("/statcard").then(response => {
      this.tableData2.push({

          name: response.data.queue,
          numbers: reponse.data.queue_count


      });
    });
}
    }
```

i recieve no data
the result of the json is :

```
{"queue_count":"4","queue":"OP_AD_WIN_HARDWARE"},{"queue_count":"35","queue":"OPBO_WIN_Fiber_pend_i"},{"queue_count":"5","queue":"OP_AD_WIN_RELOCATION"},{"queue_count":"44","queue":"OPBO_WIN_Act_pend_i"}]}
```

Comment: If you write "i recieve no data" and then post the content of a JSON response, what does that mean?

Comment: that mean on view the table is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `mounted` from `data`.
Don't add plugins multiple times.
The `element` documentation says, that `prop` is correct, not `property`.

Work on your line indentation.

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="title">Progress Queue's details Live</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content table-responsive table-full-width">
                <el-table :data="tableData2">
                    <el-table-column label="Name" prop="queue_count"></el-table-column>
                    <el-table-column class="danger" label="Numbers" prop="queue"></el-table-column>
                </el-table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import vSelect from 'vue-select';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table, TableColumn } from 'element-ui';
import ChartCard from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/ChartCard.vue';

Vue.use(Table);
Vue.use(TableColumn);

const WorldMap = () => ({
  component: import('./../Maps/WorldMap.vue'),
  loading: Loading,
  delay: 200
});

export default {
  components: {
    vSelect,
    StatsCard
  },

  data() {
    return {
      tableData2: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('/statcard').then(response => {
      this.tableData2 = response.data.queue_progress;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: wen i look on konsole ( firefox ) i have thiserror: ReferenceError: reponse is not defined

Comment: Change reponse to response. It is a spelling mistake.

Comment: I've updated my answer and your response data only creates one array entry. Maybe you'll iterate through it later.

Comment: Hi Phil i still have the same problem

Comment: Whats your console output?

Comment: wen i try this :       name: response.data.queue_progress[0].queue,
                numbers: response.data.queue_progress[0].queue_count  i have result but only the first row

Comment: I've mentioned that in my comment before. You have to iterate through your `response.data.queue_progress` array with for example `forEach` and push it while iterating, to your `tableData2` array. Also you can set `this. tableData2` equal to your `response.data`. The problem is, that I don't know your response.

Comment: Am sorry am new with this what should I exactly doing or what you need for infos ? Many thanks

Comment: Simply show me what you get from your `/statcard` endpoint. Create an pastebin entry or similiar.

Comment: queue_progress 
0 
queue_count "35"
queue "OP_AD_WIN_ACTIVATION"
1 
queue_count "21"
queue "OP_AD_WIN_FIBER"
2 
queue_count "30"
queue "OPBO_WIN_Fiber_pend_i"
3 
queue_count "40"
queue "OPBO_WIN_Act_pend_i"
4 
queue_count "4"
queue "OP_AD_WIN_RELOCATION"

Comment: "queue_progress":[{"queue_count":"35","queue":"OP_AD_WIN_ACTIVATION"},{"queue_count":"21","queue":"OP_AD_WIN_FIBER"},{"queue_count":"30","queue":"OPBO_WIN_Fiber_pend_i"},{"queue_count":"40","queue":"OPBO_WIN_Act_pend_i"},{"queue_count":"4","queue":"OP_AD_WIN_RELOCATION"}]}

Comment: I've updated my answer and set `tableData2` equal `queue_progress` from your response data and renamed the `prop` attribute value in your table.